# How do you stop a perl Dancer/Starman/Plack server?

Tags: perl, dancer, plack, starman

I started a Dancer/Starman server using:

```
sudo plackup -s Starman -p 5001 -E deployment --workers=10 -a mywebapp/bin/app.pl
```

but I'm unsure how I can stop the server. Can someone provide me with a quick way of stopping it and all the workers it has spawned?

Comment: Why `sudo`? Do you really need to run this thing as root?

Comment: Good question... probably not! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the

```
--pid /path/to/the/pid.file
```

and you can kill the process based on his `PID`

So, using the above options, you can use

```
kill $(cat /path/to/the/pid.file)
```

the `pid.file` simply stores the master's PID - don't need analyze the `ps` output...

Comment: I killed the process, but now I can't restart it using plackup. It says there's still a server running on that port

Comment: don't use `kill -9`, but simple `kill`. Now manually remove the pid-file. The `kill -9` doesn't closes opened sockets and so on...

Comment: Oops :( So I already used kill -9. Anyway to recover? Also, where do I find the pid-file? None was specified at startup. And the process seems to be continuing to serve requests on port 5001, even tho I killed it with kill -9!

Comment: if pid file is not specified, here in no one.  The recover depends on your system (i hope) - maybe after some timeout the sockets closes - but im not sure. Bad habit using `kill -9` for all things... :)

Comment: Thanks jm666 - good to know. Maybe I'll try a reboot and see if the pesky Starman job will die. It's weird tho that I can't even see it with a ps. Hardy little process!

Comment: use `lsof -i:5001` (or maybe `sudo lsof -i:5001`) to find which processes are serving that port

Answer (score 1):

`pkill -f starman`

Kill processes based on name.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can do "CTRL + C" like making a copy but Cancel in this case. Tested working.

Comment: The OP's usage of `sudo` implies that he's on Linux (or Unix in general). CTRL+C works there as well _if_ the server runs in  foreground. But I think the question was about stopping the server _with a command_.